# База записей с избранным

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно организовать хранение записей в базе с возможностью отмечать их как избранные.
Запись выглядит так.

```
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
"body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

Вот способы реализации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше поступить?

Comment: Ваша задача не совсем понятна... Избранные кем и для кого? Другими словами - одна запись может быть избрана (или иметь фаворит) не более одного раза? Т.е. в вашем примере пользователь может иметь не более одного фаворита? Если так, то я бы выбрал второй вариант, иначе первый с (`one-to-many` или `zero-to-many`) связью

Comment: Избранное пользователем, в приложении тыкает звездочку, может быть избрана только один раз.

Comment: в системе предполагается наличие более одного пользователя? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в системе предполагается более одного пользователя:)
То конечно отдельной таблицей.

Минимальный набор полей:

```
message_id - ид сообщения, или что у вас в системе помечается?
user_id - ид пользователя
```

Т.е. типичная связь *многие-ко-многим*. Каждое сообщение может быть помечено избранным несколькими пользователями; один пользователь может пометить несколько сообщений.

Comment: Нет, только один пользователь. Значит второй вариант.

Comment: @nekaneka, :)    .